# Logic App how to read secret info for use within a workflow from app settings/some other secure place?

Tags: azure-logic-apps, appsettings

Currently, I'm trying to access Graph API from within a (Standard) Logic App to search for Sharepoint documents. To do so, I try using the following flow (I need delegated permissions, application permissions cannot use search endpoint):

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/integrations-on-azure-blog/calling-graph-api-from-azure-logic-apps-using-delegated/ba-p/1997666

As one can see in the blog post above, there is a step where the following string gets passed into the body of the first request to get an access token for a delegated user:

```
grant_type=password&resource=https://graph.microsoft.com&client_id=client_id&username=serviceaccountusername&password=serviceaccountpassword&client_secret=clientsecret
```

Now the client secret and service account password are two things which I absolutely don't want to have visible in the Logic App code and/or designer screen. Is there a way to securely read these from for instance the 'app settings' (in which I could reference them from a KeyVault)? I really can't find a good way on how to achieve this and I think it's a must to not be able to read these secrets/passwords from the Designer/code view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely use a KeyVault and make sure that for all steps involved, secure the inputs/outputs where ever that secret information may be visible.

The below example is the call to get the secret and therefore, I only want the **outputs** to be secured.

[image: Settings]

[image: Secure]

**Result**

[image: Result]

With your HTTP call, it's likely that you'll only want the inputs to be secured.

Be sure to use a managed identity on your LogicApp and then assign that managed identity to the `KeyVault Secrets User` role on the KV itself.

[image: RBAC]

There's plenty of documentation on this topic ...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/create-managed-service-identity?tabs=consumption

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Should've known a task like this existed!